# Difference between energy readings from /dev/cpu/cpu0/msr and /sys/class/powercap/energy_uj

Tags: linux-kernel, energy, msr

I have found that I can measure the energy consumption using /dev/cpu/cpu0/msr file using MSR_PKG_ENERGY_STATUS, as well as reading /sys/class/powercap/energy_uj file. Although these two gives approximately the same value for a particular program, I want to know which of the two files gives more accurate result, and what is the need of having multiple interfaces to get the energy readings. Are both of them interdependent on each other?

Comment: What architecture are using (e.g. AMD, Intel. etc)? What generation processor (e.g. Haswell and Nehalem)?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know, but maybe dev/cpu/cpu0/msr gives energy per one CPU and  /sys/class/powercap/energy_uj gives full energy(if this is multithreaded program)?

Also, I think that the best way to check the above theory would be write simple multithreaded program and compare these two files.